# Unable to establish database connection on production for my Laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, production-environment

I have deployed my Laravel project on production but it seems that I am unable to establish a connection with the database I created in CPanel. I need this in order to execute some migrations and make some inserts through the platform.

I have checked that the database name, username and password are correct multiple times.

When I created the database and the user, I assigned all of the privileges to it.

My .env file looks like this:

```
APP_NAME=ReviewIt
APP_ENV=production 
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=base64:9jM6nSiyhNoAtRkjJVWofHufggaIIpPOqRH8Ne1lteE=
APP_URL=https://www.reviewit.club

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=reviewit.club
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=reviewit_main
DB_USERNAME=<username>
DB_PASSWORD="<password>"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

The mysql section in my database.php file looks like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'reviewit.club'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'reviewit_main'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '<username>'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '<password>'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'reviewit_demo'@'reviewit.club' (using password: YES) at /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=revi...', '<username>', '<password>', Array)
#1 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=revi...', 'reviewit_demo', 'reviewit98#', Array)
#2 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=revi...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(184): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#5 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(986): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(1022): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#7 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(426): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getReadPdo()
#8 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(352): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdoForSelect(true)
#9 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(685): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from i...', Array)
#10 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(652): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(360): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(44): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from i...', Array)
#13 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(169): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable('migrations')
#14 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(645): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
#15 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(106): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->repositoryExists()
#16 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(77): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
#17 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(578): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\{closure}()
#18 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(94): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->usingConnection(NULL, Object(Closure))
#19 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
#20 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#21 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#22 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#23 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(614): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#24 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#25 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(288): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#26 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#27 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(974): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#28 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(291): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#29 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(167): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#30 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(92): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#31 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(184): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\BufferedOutput))
#32 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(263): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->call('migrate', Array, NULL)
#33 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->call('migrate', Array)
#34 /home/reviewit/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/CommandController.php(18): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array)
#35 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\CommandController->migrate()
#36 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('migrate', Array)
#37 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\CommandController), 'migrate')
#38 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#39 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#40 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#49 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#52 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#56 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#58 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#63 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#64 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#65 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#66 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#67 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#68 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#69 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#70 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#71 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#72 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#73 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#74 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#75 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#76 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#77 /home/reviewit/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#78 /home/reviewit/public_html/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#79 /home/reviewit/public_html/index.php(21): require_once('/home/reviewit/...')
#80 {main}
"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if your DB_PASSWORD contain special character then you have use quotes DB_PASSWORD="sss#@124%$#"

Comment: I did use quotes

Comment: then verify it connect directly in mysql terminal or phpmyadmin

Comment: probably some cache issue. are you getting any error??

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added it right now

Comment: `reviewit_demo`, is the user name correct??

Comment: Yes, I mentioned i checked it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't give permissions to that user so he can connect or do anything on that database.

When creating a custom database user you must do these things:

```
// create a user with all permissions like root
CREATE USER 'dbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

// grant privileges on some database.table or all
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'; // allow everything on all databases (not recommended, this is almost like a root user)

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON blog.* TO 'dbuser'@'localhost'; // allow everything on 'blog' database

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

---

To quickly check what are your 'grants' (what are you allowed to do) run this inside DBMS:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```